# Use the Same Cloud Function in Android as I do in iOS While Creating a Stripe Customer

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a stripeID when customers register a new account on my Android app like they do on my iOS app. My question is - is it possible to use the same Cloud Function to create the Stripe Customer in my Android app, or do I need to create a brand new Functions folder for Android? Thank you!

**Cloud Function**

```
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {

    const email = data.email
    const uid = context.auth.uid
    console.log(uid)

    if (uid === null) {
      console.log('Illegal access attempt due to unauthenticated attempt.')
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Illegal access attempt')
    }

    return stripe.customers
    .create({ email: email })
    .then((customer) => {
      return customer["id"];
    })
    .then((customerId) => {
      admin.database().ref("customers").child(uid).update({
        stripeId: customerId,
        email: email,
        id: uid
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "internal",
        " Unable to create Stripe user : " + err
      );
    });
})
```

**Kotlin Functions**

```
registerViewStubSignUpButton.setOnClickListener {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(registerViewStubEmailTextView.text.toString(), registerViewStubPasswordTextView.text.toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (!it.isSuccessful) return@addOnCompleteListener

                    // else if successful
                    uploadImageToFirebaseStorage()
                    uploadStripeCustomer()

                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to create user: ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
        }

private fun uploadImageToFirebaseStorage() {

        if (selectedPhotoUri == null) return

        val filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/customer_profile_images/$filename")

        ref.putFile(selectedPhotoUri!!)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                    saveCustomerToFirebaseDatabase(it.toString())
                }
            }

    }

    private fun saveCustomerToFirebaseDatabase(profileImageUrl: String) {

        val registerStub = findViewById<ViewStub>(R.id.registerStub)
        val registerViewStubFullnameTextView = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.fullnameInputTextView)
        val registerViewStubUsernameTextView = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.usernameTextInputView)
        val registerViewStubEmailTextView = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.emailInputTextView)

        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/customers/$uid")

        val customer = Customer(uid, registerViewStubFullnameTextView.text.toString(), registerViewStubUsernameTextView.text.toString(),
                                registerViewStubEmailTextView.text.toString(), profileImageUrl)

        ref.setValue(customer)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                registerStub.alpha = 0f
                finish()
            }

    }

    private fun uploadStripeCustomer() {



    }
```

Comment: There's no reason why you can't share the same HTTP function between your Android and iOS applications, assuming there's nothing specific to either in there.

Comment: Thank you! Thought so but needed to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the use case. If the Firebase Cloud Function does the same task for both the  iOS and the Android applications then using just one should work. If there is some different use case for the iOS and the Android applications then one should use two different Cloud Functions.

In your case, it seems, you are creating a `stripeID` when a customer registers for a new account in both the iOS and the Android applications, so it is wise to use one Firebase Cloud Functions for both the iOS and the Android applications.

Comment: Thank you! Thought so, I just wanted to check.